# What to do before reading The World as Will and Representation

Tags: schopenhauer

What should I do/read before reading the main work of Arthur Schopenhauer. I am 50 pages in and it seems like there has to be some pre knowledge before beginning this book.
Any advices?

Comment: [Immanuel Kant](https://www.iep.utm.edu/kantview/).

Comment: Thank you @MauroALLEGRANZA !

Comment: You are welcome :-) Maybe useful [Schopenhauer’s Critique of Kant](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schopenhauer/#3).

Comment: I agree, some understanding of Kant's philosophy is necessary for understanding Schopenhauer, because Kant is Schopenhauer's main foil. I also recommend [a short introduction to Schopenhauer](https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B005G6O38S/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=&sr=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before (or while) reading Schopenhauer, you need :

- some basic knowledge of Plato's metaphysics and epistemology;
- some basic knowledge of the Christian doctrine and of oriental  philosophy/religion;
- Kant's *Critique of Pure Reason*, or its popular summary (by Kant himself): *Prolegomena to any future metaphysics*;
- Kant's *Groundings for  the metaphysics of morals*;
- a dictionary of Kant's terminology, such as *Kant-Lexikon* by Eisler.

After reading Schopenhauer, you may need :

- *Christian help for Depresssion* [sic] by Pat Buckley, or
- *Depression Self Help: 9 Quick Ways In A Step-By-Step Formula To Beat Depression Today Without Drugs!* by Allan Twain.

Good luck! :)